# como puedo agrandar los iconos de las pestañas del TabLayout

Tags: android

estoy probando un menu que las pestañas del TabLayout tiene texto e imagne, la imagen que se muestra es algo pequeña, como puedo aumentar el tamaño de las imagenes que estan como iconos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    setupViewPager();

    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabLayout();
}

private void setupTabLayout() {
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.google_maps);
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.google_search);
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.gmail);
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.google_maps);
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(4).setIcon(R.drawable.google_search);
    mTabLayout.getTabAt(5).setIcon(R.drawable.gmail);
}

private void setupViewPager() {
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    Fragment fragUno = new FragmentTab();
    Fragment fragDos = new FragmentTab();
    Fragment fragTres = new FragmentTab();
    Fragment fragCuatro = new FragmentTab();
    Fragment fragCinco = new FragmentTab();
    Fragment fragSeis = new FragmentTab();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("text", "Primera Pantalla - Fragment");
    fragUno.setArguments(args);

    args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("text", "Segunga Pantalla - Fragment");
    fragDos.setArguments(args);

    args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("text", "Tercera Pantalla - Fragment");
    fragTres.setArguments(args);

    args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("text", "Cuarta Pantalla - Fragment");
    fragCuatro.setArguments(args);

    args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("text", "Quinta Pantalla - Fragment");
    fragCinco.setArguments(args);

    args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("text", "Secta Pantalla - Fragment");
    fragSeis.setArguments(args);

    adapter.addFragment(fragUno, "hola");
    adapter.addFragment(fragDos, "Dos");
    adapter.addFragment(fragTres, "Tres");
    adapter.addFragment(fragCuatro, "Cuatro");
    adapter.addFragment(fragCinco, "Cinco");
    adapter.addFragment(fragSeis, "Seis");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> listFragment = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> listFragmentTitle = new ArrayList<>();

    MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return listFragment.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listFragment.size();
    }

    void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        listFragment.add(fragment);
        listFragmentTitle.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return listFragmentTitle.get(position);
    }
}

}
```

**custom_tab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/iconTab"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textTab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

El `TabLayout` por defecto, creo que no tiene ningún método para asignar tamaño a las imágenes.

Lo que podrías hacer en su lugar, es crearte un layout para las pestaña pudiendo así, darle el formato que quieras y mucho mas editable.

En primer lugar create el layout (customt_tab.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/iconTab"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textTab" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Luego para cada una de las pestañas que quieras crear se las asignas al `TabLayout`

```
    View tab1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    tab1.findViewById(R.id.iconTab).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.google_maps);
    tab1.findViewById(R.id.textTab).setText("MENU UNO");
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tab1));
```

Luego seria cosa de ir ajustando cada componente en su sitio ajustándolo en el `custom_tab.xml`

**UPDATE**

```
public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        // Devuelve el numero totales de pestañas
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        // Mostrara el fragment que devolvera a pestaña seleccionada
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - Este mostrara FirstFragment
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
            case 1: // Fragment # 0 - Este mostrara FirstFragment con diferente titulo
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");
            case 2: // Fragment # 1 - Este mostrara el SecondFragment
                return SecondFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 3");
            default:
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Devuelve el titulo del fragment 
        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "Page " + position;
        }

    }
```

Este es un ejemplo de la implementación de `MyPagerAdapter`

Comment: Gracias @Hictus cuando llegue a casa compruebo el código que me dices, pero creo que para los iconos tiene ya su layout, el menú lo he sacado de aquí https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=95mzL5WWc68

Comment: No se como meter ese codigo en cada pestaña, me muestra los iconos fuera http://funkyimg.com/i/2AU3p.png, para poder darles algo mas de tamaño a los iconos, se podria hacer algo mas pequeño el Toolbar, no se si en este caso tiene ese nombre o es ActionBar, es donde esta puesto el texto "menu pruebas"

Comment: Imagino que te habrás bajado el código de [GitHub], bien en la clase `ActivityTabIconText.java` tienes un método que se llama `setupTabLayout()` dentro de ese método, deberías reemplazar el código, por el que te he puesto yo, de esa manera solo aparecerán las tuyas

Comment: Si baje ese codigo, y lo pongo donde me dice, pero ahora que has puesto esa nueva linea de codigo me esta mostando error en **setText** mira esta captura http://funkyimg.com/i/2AWty.png

Comment: Cierto, seguramente tengas q hacerle un casting a TextView, prueba a cambiarla por ((TextView)tab1.findViewById(R.id.textTab)).setText("MENU Uno");

Comment: Estupendo ahora si aparece, lo malo es que en el apartado **setupViewPager()** antes cuando pulsaba uno menu me lleva a su correspondiente apartado para mostrar una pagina web, ahora no hace nada, el codigo que tengo puesto en el setupViewPager() lo he puesto en el primer post.

Comment: Los fragments se deberían agregar en la implementacion que tengas hecha del `MyFragmentPagerAdapter` dentro del metodo `getItem()`. Edita tu pregunta para añadir el código de dicha implementacion y ver que puede estar fallando.

Comment: Gracias Hictus voy a intentarlo.

Comment: Hola de nuevo @Hictus, perdona sé que ha pasado tiempo, pero dejé aparcado este proyecto al perder todo, perdí el disco duro y no conseguí reanimar el disco duro para intentar salvar algo, te he dejado el código como lo tengo, por si quieres seguir ayudándome, al poner el código que me pasaste no conseguía agrandar los iconos por más cambios que estoy realizando, por eso te he dejado en el primer post como lo tenía antes de modificar nada.